# Python to extract / parse nested json data stored in Mariadb

Tags: python, json, mariadb

So I have inherited a "simple" web application written in PHP and stores most of the transaction data in one table on MariaDB by using json in a long_text field.

I need to parse out the data so it can be put into a traditional relational database table(s).  Preferably using SQL and/or Python.

This is the current table structure

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+        
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |        
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+        
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |        
| client_name   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |        
| invoice_total | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |        
| invoice       | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |        
| user_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |        
| created       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |        
| uuid          | varchar(70)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |        
| paid          | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |        
| paid_date     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |                              
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here to one record of the existing data.

```
341, 'Dave Moreman', '4616.75', '{"data":{"id":"341","clientCompanyName":"Dave Moreman","clientAddress":"18656 86th Ave, <br />Zwingle,Utah 50032, <br />United States, <br /> 563 555 1212.","job_descr":"Swine","Invoice":{"itemNo":["1","1","1","DF","F"],"itemName":["Pumped out of hog building, hauled 4.5 miles and applied to field (Jakes House)","Pumped out of hog building, hauled 3.5 miles and applied to field (Daughters house)","Pumped out of hog building, hauled 4 miles and applied to field(By your house)","Diesel Fuel","Finance charge"],"price":["0.0155",".0145",".015","1","1"],"quantity":["169000","88000","36002","113.00","68.22"],"total":["2619.50","1276.00","540.03","113.00","68.22"]},"notes":"281,000 total gallons","subTotal":"4616.75","tax":"","taxAmount":"0","totalAftertax":"4616.75","amountPaid":"","amountDue":"4616.75","companyAddress":""},"invoice_btn":"Save Invoice"}', 1, '2018-04-30 22:21:24', '5ae7dd3402994', 1, '2018-06-22 12:56:39'
```

Here is what I have so.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                        
import pymysql.cursors                                                          

# Connect to the database                                                       
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',                                  
                             user='user',                                    
                             password='password',                             
                             db='shaggy',                            
                             charset='utf8mb4',                                 
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


try:                                                                            
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:                                         
        # Read a single record                                                  
        sql = "select invoice from invoices where id = 341"                     
        cursor.execute(sql)                                                     
        result = cursor.fetchall()                                              
        print(result)                                                           
        print("-------------------------------------")                          

        for row in result:                                                      
            print(row["invoice"][0])                                            
            print(row["invoice"][1])                                            
            print(row["invoice"][2])                                            
            print(row["invoice"][3])                                            
except Exception as e:                                                          
    print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))                                    
finally:                                                                        
    connection.close()
```

And this is my result.

```
[{'invoice': '{"data":{"id":"341","clientCompanyName":"Dave Morehead","clientAddress":"18656 86th Ave, <br />Bernard,Iowa 52032, <br />United States, <br /> 563 249 5319.","job_descr":"Swine","Invoice":{"itemNo":["1","1","1","DF","F"],"itemName":["Pumped out of hog building, hauled 4.5 miles and applied to field (Jakes House)","Pumped out of hog building, hauled 3.5 miles and applied to field (Daughters house)","Pumped out of hog building, hauled 4 miles and applied to field(By your house)","Diesel Fuel","Finance charge"],"price":["0.0155",".0145",".015","1","1"],"quantity":["169000","88000","36002","113.00","68.22"],"total":["2619.50","1276.00","540.03","113.00","68.22"]},"notes":"281,000 total gallons","subTotal":"4616.75","tax":"","taxAmount":"0","totalAftertax":"4616.75","amountPaid":"","amountDue":"4616.75","companyAddress":""},"invoice_btn":"Save Invoice"}'}]
-------------------------------------
{
"
d
a
```

My question is how do I keep working my way through the data getting key:value information?

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch the row.
2. Use a python function to turn the JSON into a python structure.
3. Walk through the structure using python code.
4. Create `INSERT` statements as needed, and execute them.

That is, steps 2 and 3 are better done via the application language than via SQL.

Comment: #1 - already done as I have shown.  #2 - that's what I'm trying to do, hence my question.  #3 - that's what I'm trying to do, hence my question.  #4 - obviously, which is why I didn't ask.

Comment: I have been over the document you linked to several times but I'm still at a loss.